# Редирект ссылок

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.

В общем, есть вордпресс, на нем нужно сделать редирект ссылок вида `http://tatata.com/politics/page/2/` на `http://tatata.com/category/politics/page/2/`, то есть тупо вставить слово category после домена. Есть ньюанс: редирект должен быть, только если есть `/page/` в ссылке. Модрерайт включен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^politics/page/([0-9]+)/ /category/politics/page/$1/ [R=301,L]
```